# cognito trigger VerifyAuthChallengeResponse share information with PreTokenGeneration

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I've implemented a custom authentication flow in AWS Cognito. I've configured the following triggers within the AWS Cognito User Pool:

- Define Auth Challenge
- Create Auth Challenge
- Verify Auth Challenge Response

On the front end, I'm utilizing Vue.js for the Sign-In process, employing the following code:

```
import { CognitoUser, CognitoUserPool, AuthenticationDetails } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js"

doSignIn({ email, password }) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    email = email.toLowerCase().trim()
    const authenticationData = {
      Username: email,
      Password: password,
    }
    const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData)
    const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolDetails)
    const userData = {
      Username: email,
      Pool: userPool,
    }
    const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData)

    const onSuccess = () => {
      resolve(true)
    }

    const onFailure = (err) => {
      console.log("onFailure:", err)
      resolve(err)
    }

    const newPasswordRequired = () => {
     //
    }

    const customChallenge = (challengeParameters) => {
      const otp = window.prompt(challengeParameters.prompt)
      cognitoUser.sendCustomChallengeAnswer(otp, {
        onSuccess,
        onFailure,
      })
    }

    cognitoUser.setAuthenticationFlowType("CUSTOM_AUTH")
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess,
      onFailure,
      newPasswordRequired,
      customChallenge,
    })
  })
}
```

My concern arises from the fact if I do not explicitly set 'cognitoUser.setAuthenticationFlowType("CUSTOM_AUTH")' in the front end, users can still sign in successfully, but without triggering the createAuthChallenge that creates the OTP challenge.
Users obtain a valid token that passes through the API gateway without any issue, which is not what I expected. I want to ensure that the user has completed the challenge before obtaining a token.

I'm looking for a solution to either enforce the use of 'cognitoUser.setAuthenticationFlowType("CUSTOM_AUTH")' without relying on client-side configuration or to determine at the API gateway when a token was created following successful challenge completion.

I thought the easiest way would be for the event object in the Lambda function would contain a property that would indicate whether the token was created following a successful challenge. However, I have not found a way to achieve this.

The other way I considered involves utilizing a shared property in the response within 'verifyAuthChallengeResponse', which could then be accessed during 'preTokenGeneration'. If the preTokenGeneration was triggered without going through the 'verifyAuthChallengeResponse', I would throw an error. However, I'm not sure if that's possible or even the best approach.

```
exports.verifyAuthChallengeResponse = async event => {
  console.log("verifyAuthChallengeResponse ~ JSON.event:", JSON.stringify(event))
  event.response.answerCorrect = event.request.privateChallengeParameters.answer === event.request.challengeAnswer
  //For intance, I could use a shared property here
  event.response.DATA_SHARED = event.response.answerCorrect
  return event
}

exports.preTokenGeneration = async event => {
  console.log("preTokenGeneration ~ JSON.event:", JSON.stringify(event))
  if (!event.response.DATA_SHARED) 
    throw new Error("The user did not pass the custom challenge")
  return event
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.